# Conditional print formatting

Tags: python

I have a function like this:

```
def PrintXY(x,y):
    print('{:<10,.3g} {:<10,.3g}'.format(x,y) )
```

When I run this it's perfect:

```
>>> x = 1/3
>>> y = 5/3
>>> PrintXY(x,y)
0.333      1.67
```

But let's say that `x` and `y` are not guaranteed to exist:

```
>>> PrintXY(x, None)
unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__
```

In that case I'd like to print nothing, just empty space.  I tried:

```
def PrintXY(x,y):
    if y is None: 
        y = ''
    print('{:<10,.3g} {:<10,.3g}'.format(x,y) )
```

But that gives:

```
ValueError: Unknown format code 'g' for object of type 'str'
```

How can I print whitespace if the number doesn't exist, and proper formating when the number does exist?  I'd rather not print 0 or -9999 to signify an error.

Comment: `y = ' '`. You are missing the space in this line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have separated it out to make it clear what the statements achieve. You can combine this into one line but it would make the code a bit harder to read

```
def PrintXY(x,y):
    x_str = '{:.3g}'.format(x) if x else ''
    y_str = '{:.3g}'.format(y) if y else ''
    print('{:<10} {:<10}'.format(x_str, y_str))
```

Then running gives

```
In [179]: PrintXY(1/3., 1/2.)
     ...: PrintXY(1/3., None)
     ...: PrintXY(None, 1/2.)
     ...:
0.333      0.5
0.333
           0.5
```

Another alternative to make sure your format remains consistent is to do

```
def PrintXY(x,y):
    fmtr = '{:.3g}'
    x_str = fmtr.format(x) if x else ''
    y_str = fmtr.format(y) if y else ''
    print('{:<10} {:<10}'.format(x_str, y_str))
```

Comment: imho best answer because of flexibility, readibility & modularity!

Comment: Yes, it's extendible for any number of parameters. I like this one too.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
def PrintXY(x=None, y=None):        
    print(''.join(['{:<10,.3g}'.format(n) if n is not None else '' for n in [x, y]]))
```

This you could easily expand to use `x`, `y` and `z`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use different `print` commands like this:

```
def PrintXY(x,y):
    if y is None: 
        print('{:<10,.3g}'.format(x) )
    else:
        print('{:<10,.3g} {:<10,.3g}'.format(x,y) )
```

Comment: Was a nice idea, but in reality I have more than just two parameters, all of which could be `None`, the number of combinations would be too much to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can make code more readable and easy to understand the condition that you have in your problem statement, you can try this also:

```
def PrintXY(x,y):
    formatter = None

    if x is None and y is None:
        x, y = '', ''
        formatter = '{} {}'
    if x is None:
        y = ''
        formatter = '{} {:<10,.3g}'
    if y is None:
        x = ''
        formatter = '{:<10,.3g} {}'
    else:
        formatter = '{:<10,.3g} {:<10,.3g}'

    print(formatter.format(x,y))
```